# H264 streaming to iOS not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, video-streaming, h.264

I am trying to get a video stream from a camera and show it on an iOS app. The camera sends the stream via udp port. For that is simple, I am just opening a `GCDAsyncUDPSocket` and start listening on the delegate. My problem starts when the data starts to arrive.

I have the `NSData` object that arrives to the delegate and, as the stream is H264 and following the info from WWDC2014 I strip the `NSData` into smaller pieces, separating it by 0x000001. That should be the NALUs and for each one I get the type:

```
- (int)getNALUType:(NSData *)NALU {
    uint8_t * bytes = (uint8_t *) NALU.bytes;

    return bytes[0] & 0x1F;
}
```

If type is 7 or 8 I create the SPS and PPS objects and when I have both of them I create the format description with `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets`.

Finally, having the format description, I start adding the objects with type 1 and 5 (IDR and non-IDR pictures) to the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` block buffer.

I am using the code from here to process the NALUs:

https://github.com/niswegmann/H264Streamer/blob/master/H264Streamer/ViewController.m

and this is how I process the data that arrives from the stream:

```
-(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext{

    UInt8 TxDataBytes[10];
    int TxDataIndex = 0;

    TxDataBytes[TxDataIndex++] = 0x00;
    TxDataBytes[TxDataIndex++] = 0x00;
    TxDataBytes[TxDataIndex++] = 0x01;

    NSData *NALUStartData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&TxDataBytes length:TxDataIndex];

    NSArray* NALUArray = [data componentsSplitByDataBytes:NALUStartData];

    for (NSData* NALU in NALUArray) {
        [self parseNALU:NALU];
    }
}
```

`componentSplitByDataBytes` is from this repo:

https://github.com/watr/NSData-SplitByData

I am pretty sure that my problem is how I get the NALUs from the `NSData`, but I don't know what else to try.